# What is the fastest way to bytewise examine the contetnt of quadword

Tags: algorithms, testing

I have the following byte: `0x0A` and I need to test if a quadword contains it or no using standard bitwise operarion (or, nor, xor). For instance:

0x1689FFBB768922AC ---> false
0x106489320A792399 ---> true

Unfortunately I cannot use intel SSE2 extension because this will make the code heavily depndent on the platform.

Can we find some bitmask to bitwise or with? Or maybe something else...?

Comment: If you're looking for specific implementation details, you might have more luck on https://stackoverflow.com/ .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it can be done.  Here is one reasonable approach.  First XOR the value with `0x0A0A..0A`:

```
t = x ^ 0x0A0A0A0A0A0A0A0A0A0A0A0A0A0A0A0A;
```

So now the problem becomes testing whether `y` contains a zero byte.  First we'll replace every byte with a single bit that is `1` if the byte is non-zero, or `0` if the byte is zero:

```
u = t | (t>>4);
u = u | (u>>2);
u = u | (u>>1);
```

(Here we only care about the least significant bit of each byte; the remaining bit positions hold garbage that we don't care about.)  Now we'll flip each of those bits:

```
v = ~u;
```

At this point the LSB of each byte is `1` if the original value contained a `0x0A` there, or `0` otherwise.  So, we'll test whether any of these bits are `1`:

```
w = v | (v>>64);
w = w | (w>>32);
w = w | (w>>16);
w = w | (w>>8);
y = w & 1;
```

At this point, `y` is the result you are looking for: it will be `1` if the original value had a `0x0A` byte anywhere, or `0` otherwise.